# Latency (wait ttfb) on EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, configuration, apache-2.4, latency

My application is crawling a website. I use this crawler :

- https://github.com/rfussien/leboncoin-crawler

On my dev environment, the latency is acceptable (3-4 sec) but on my prod server (ec2 T2.micro Linux/Amazon) there is a 30 seconde latency (wait ttfb).

I tested the same code in another server (1&1) and there is a acceptable latency (3-4 sec). So **the problem is not inside the code**, but about the server config.

I have tried :

- check the php conf (php.ini)
- add cache to php (Zend OPCache)
- add apache 2 vary: accept-encoding header
- test a t2.medium instance
- change the region of my instance

I found this similar question :
[PHP + Apache long wait time](https://serverfault.com/questions/564984/php-apache-long-wait-time) but I think that my ec2 volume is an EBS SSD so there is no access time issue.

This unsolved question is also link to mine : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34299038/deployed-web-application-long-ajax-wait-ttfb-time

An extract of vmstat during the request:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx ~]$ vmstat 1
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu-----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 0  0   1580 534472  29696 240356    0    0     2    31   14   41  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 534456  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   19   43  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 534456  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   12   37  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 534456  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   12   38  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 534456  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   15   45  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 534456  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   18   49  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 534456  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   12   38  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   32   60  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   13   39  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   17   45  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     4   16   49  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   13   40  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   13   38  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   13   38  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29696 240356    0    0     0     0   16   47  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29700 240352    0    0     0     4   17   48  0  0 99  1  0    
 0  0   1580 533544  29700 240356    0    0     0     0   15   39  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29700 240356    0    0     0     0   13   39  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29700 240356    0    0     0     0   13   39  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29700 240356    0    0     0     0   17   46  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29700 240356    0    0     0     4   19   50  0  0 100  0  0   
 0  0   1580 533544  29700 240356    0    0     0     0   15   41  0  0 100  0  0
```

[UPDATE]
Right now I know that this latence is due to a GuzzleHttp\Client request :

```
(string) $this->httpClient->get($url)->getBody();
```

My security group seems ok, all is allowed from outbound and HTTP is allowed from inbound. My network out also seems ok (40,000 - 50,000 bytes when I request).

I'm thinking that this should be a problem with mpm_prefork_module...

[UPDATE 2]
From SSH, If I curl http://google.fr, I have no latency. If I curl my specific url (http://www.leboncoin.fr) the latency is >30 sec. It's specific to my AWS Ec2 with this URL.

Comment: What are the iowait and CPU steal percentages at?

Comment: My CPU is always under 5%.I use vmstat 1 to see IOWait, it seems to be 0 or 1 during the request.

Comment: Is the HTTP request to a specific website? If so, how long does `curl http://example.com/` with that website take to return data back? 30 seconds sounds almost like a DNS timeout or fallback.

Comment: Yes it's specific to the URL ! (no latency with google or stack). But after the 30 seconds my page is loaded. Can you tell me more @ceejayoz ?

Comment: @JulienMalige Next, I'd try `dig example.com` and see if that takes a while. If so, you have a DNS issue, probably fixable by updating `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: @ceejayoz With dig example.com or dig myspecificurl, there is no error and the query time is under 1ms

Comment: Are you able to share the URL?

Comment: Of course : http://www.leboncoin.fr (my ec2 is in Frankfurt)

Comment: If in ssh I try to curl the same url, I have the same latency..